# Create multiple exact FXML objects in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to create multiple fxml objects inside the window, using code in fxml once. But they are not appearing more than once.
Here is my controller code:

```java
public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane plot = new AnchorPane();

    @FXML
    void AddPlotBlock(ActionEvent event) {
        this.plot.setMinHeight(110.0D);
        this.plot.setMinWidth(250.0D);
        this.plot.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey");
    }
```

And FXML:

```xml
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" style="-fx-background-color: #301934;">
        <children>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="plot"/>
        </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're doing here. What's the relationship between the FXML and what you described? If you want to add new blocks in your `addPlotBlock()` method, then that method should create a new `AnchorPane` (either directly in code or by loading an FXML). Which container are these supposed to be added to (the root `AnchorPane` defined in the FXML, the single child `AnchorPane` called `plot` defined in the FXML, or something else)? And it is *always* incorrect to initialize something annotated `@FXML`.

Comment: That sounds like something you need to do in code and not FXML.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if you are laying things out in a grid. If you are have a look at `GridPane` and/or `TilePane`.

Comment: @James_D First I wanted to create AnchorPane with root using but I don't know how to show my widget. If I just declare anchorpane it won't show in the screen, so I founded that if I declare object in FXML I can show my widget and its work but only for one widget and not multiply, so if you can please tell how to show widget in controller class. I know if create loop in application class it works but for me it doesn't work in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found how to fix it.
To make this you need to change id in FXML main file not in children but in pane (my AnchorPane) and then make AnchorPane with exact name in controller.
Then you can initialyze your blocks or anything inside controller and add it in pane.
Here is my solution.

controller >

```
plots.getChildren().add(card); // plots is id
```

upper command is inside button click.

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane plot = new AnchorPane();

@FXML
public AnchorPane plots;
```

plot is objects. You can place infinite objects (if you have memory)

plots is id of anchorpane.

FXML anchorpane

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="plots" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" style="-fx-background-color: #301934;" />
```

So anchorpane have id and you add child arguments (plot) to main pane (plots).
Thanks for commenting, and rules.

Comment: beware: you __must not__ instantiate a field that's annotated with @fxml (aka: meant to be injected) - here you can probably simply remove the annotation, if it is not meant to be created by the fxml